# What to put in a Stored Procedure documentation?

Tags: documentation

I was tasked to document our stored procedures.

- Target audience: Technical
- Purpose: To have a good documentation in preparation for
  migration.

I'm assuming someone has already done it.

Comment: All the "Why do we do it like this?" questions along with their answers.  I.e. try to capture the design phase.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At a minimum, you document it like you would a function or method in source code. For example:

- What does the stored procedure do? Does it update or modify any tables or just read values?
- What are the arguments? What are their allowed values? Can they be NULL?
- What is returned? Is it a scalar value? Is it a table? If so, what are the fields and what do their values mean? Is there a single row or multiple rows?
- Give an example of its use
- Are there related or similar stored procedures? For example, is it normally used in conjunction with another stored procedure?

Depending on your environment, the following may or may not apply:

- Should it be called within a transaction or not?
- Are there any special security requirements? For example, does the caller need access to particular tables?
- Are there any known bugs that are not fixed due to backwards compatibility reasons?
- Does this stored procedure supersede other stored procedures? Is it obsolete or deprecated?
- Is the stored procedure written by hand or auto generated? If it is auto generated, what tool generated it?
- Does the procedure deal with sensitive information like credit card details, hashed passwords or Personally Identifiable Information (PII)?

For the actual documentation, the best experience I had was using a Wiki. Each stored proc had its own page and so the documentation was versioned independently with an easily accessible history and change list. Users could subscribe to changes via E-mail and the documentation was always in an easily accessible location.

Comment: Great inputs akton. How would you manage document revisions? Do you store the document in a revision control system? Or do you keep a table of changes in the document itself?

Comment: @Joset I added paragraph to the answer talking about Wiki use.

Comment: I appreciate all your inputs.

Comment: You might want to add: If a resultset is returned, is it a single row or multiple rows?

Comment: @jmoreno Good idea. I have updated the text.